# Which is the correct key frame intervall settings for ffmpeg stream to Periscope

Tags: ffmpeg

I will stream to Periscope with ffmpeg.
The requirements of Periscope are:

•Framerate: 30fps
•Keyframe interval: every 2 seconds (OBS) or Keyframe every 45 frames (Wirecast)

I have follew ffmpeg command line:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -deinterlace -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 960x540 -preset superfast -vb 1200k -maxrate 1200k -r 30  -bufsize 8000k  -c:a aac -b:a 96k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://de.pscp.tv:80/xxxxxxxxx
```

How can i set

```
Keyframe interval: every 2 seconds (OBS) or Keyframe every 45 frames (Wirecast)
```

on this command line

Answer (score 4):

Add `-g 60` for a 2 second interval.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -deinterlace -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 960x540 -preset superfast -vb 1200k -maxrate 1200k -r 30 -g 60 -bufsize 8000k -c:a aac -b:a 96k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://de.pscp.tv:80/xxxxxxxxx
```